# How Can I make these two boxes. P.S I am new to flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]
**The image I have added below. I**

Comment: This is not a "we code it for you" service. If you have a specific question, please add the code so we can help you.

Comment: Well I am so sorry..I just started my development journey..I am new to all these things, but learning day by day from guys like you..  Will take this as a constructive criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following code:

```
Row(
     children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(child: OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Message"))),
     Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {},child: Text("Connect"))),
       ],
   ),
```

you can see other customization for buttons styles from the [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons)